# Docker volume with Grunt file watch

Tags: macos, docker, gruntjs, watch

I'm porting an existing project with Grunt file watches to a Docker development container. The source files are bind-mounted into the container, and Grunt watches the files for changes (this can probably be optimized, but my current concern is: simply get the current setup working within Docker).

On the Mac, I'm experiencing enormous CPU usage, so I read the [performance tuning guide](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/#tuning-with-consistent-cached-and-delegated-configurations) for osxfs. The guide mentions the `cached` and `delegated` volume modes.

The description for `delegated` says:

> the container’s view is authoritative
>   (permit delays before updates on the container appear in the host)

For `cached`:

> […] provides all the guarantees of the delegated configuration, and some additional guarantees around the visibility of writes performed by containers. As such, cached typically improves the performance of read-heavy workloads, at the cost of some temporary inconsistency between the host and the container.

In comparison to **which** setting does `cached` **improve** performance? Is "read-heavy workloads" seen from the container's perspective?

To cut a long story short: What's the optimal setting to reduce CPU usage for a development environment which uses file watches? `cached` or `delegated`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I did some testing and here's my results. Setup:

- MacBook Air 11", early 2014
- macOS 10.12.6
- Docker 17.06.0-ce-mac19 (18663)
- watch task polling for ~ 1,000 files

The culprit processes eating up CPU cycles in the host are `hyperkit` and `com.docker.osxfs`. The following percentage values are the median CPU usage taken over five samples:

- `delegated`: 18.7 % hyperkit + 0.0 % com.docker.osxfs = **18.7 %**
- `cached`: 24.3 % hyperkit + 0.1 % com.docker.osxfs = **24.4 %**
- `default` aka. `consistent`: 152.0 % hyperkit + 68.9 % com.docker.osxfs = **220.9 % (!)**

Functionality-wise I didn't notice any difference. When changing a file outside the container the changes were picked up virtually immediately by the watch in each of the three cases. So I'm going to use the `delegated` mode now.

Comment: Good to read that as I have exactly the same setup but totally unable to get Grunt to watch any change :/ I am on this since about 5 hours...

Comment: @MrUpsidown On the Mac this worked out-of-the-box afair (no matter which of the three settings I took .. this was only about CPU usage optimization). My Windows colleagues have to run a tool called 'docker-volume-watcher' though, else wise grunt within the Docker environment will not pick up any changes at all.

Comment: I was having issues with my Grunt installation. Got this fixed now and I am also using delegated mode (for mounting my custom theme folder for a Magento 2 setup) as it is definitely the fastest method.